# Is there a better way of retrieving the name of an acf pagelink type from current post?

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, id

- I'm using Advanced Custom Fields.
- I have a registered `bookitall_roomstype` custom post type.
- I have a registered `bookitall_bookings` as another custom post type.
- In the bookitall_bookings there is a field called
  `bookitall_roomstype` that is stored as a `pagelink` (acf "type"). (This 
  looks like a permalink to the actual roomtype (It's NOT stored as a 
  title/name)

I'm setting up certain columns (and their values) to be shown. Now I want the roomtype's name to be shown. I'm doing like below...

**This is a snippet of my code. This snippet retrieves the NAME `roomtype_name` of the pagelink-type `bookitall_roomstype`**:

```
$allfields_currentpost = get_fields();
$args = array(
          'posts_per_page'   => -1,
          'offset'           => 0,
          'orderby'          => 'ID',
          'order'            => 'ASC',
          'post_type'        => 'bookitall_roomtypes'
);
$roomtypes = get_posts( $args );  

$pagelink = get_field('bookitall_roomstype'); //pagelink acf type        
$roomtypes_slugs = array();
foreach ( $roomtypes as $r ) {
    $roomtypes_slugs[] = get_permalink( $r->ID);
}
$arrkey = (array_search($pagelink, $roomtypes_slugs));
$roomtype_name = '';
if ( $arrkey !== false ) {
    $roomtype_name = $roomtypes[$arrkey]->post_title;
}
```

***The above do actually work*** (I put it here if someone have the same issue and I also **want to know if there is a better/simpler way of achieving above?** (getting the roomtype's name from current post)

I've tried to use `url to postid( $pagelink )` and `get_page_by_path( $pagelink )` but those only returns 0 (which means no object is returned). If a post had been returned I could use `$post->post_title`.

UPDATE:
**New code** (thanks to @Milo !!!):

```
$allfields_currentpost = get_fields(false, false);        
$roomtype_id = $allfields_currentpost['bookitall_roomstype'];  
$roomtype_name = get_the_title($roomtype_id);
```

(I'm jusing the other field values from the current post as well, therefore I'm using `get_fields()` instead of `get_field()`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The page link field](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/page-link/) actually stores the post ID, which gets formatted internally by the `get_field` function on output. The 3rd argument for `get_field` lets you disable that output formatting so you just get the ID back, which you can then use to get title and permalink for that post:

```
$post_id = get_field( 'bookitall_roomstype', false, false );
if( $post_id ):
    echo get_the_permalink( $post_id );
    echo get_the_title( $post_id );
endif;
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! Did not know that about the output options. IMO false should be default value, but I guess you can't get it all ;-) (ACF is fantastic)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to get all `bookitall_roomstype` in lines 2-9 of your code. You really only want to pull room types that are assigned to the current `bookitall_bookings` CPT.

As far as the "pagelink" field, this seems like an unsafe way of calling the information. What if a permalink changed someday? It seems like it would be both safer and more efficient to save post IDs instead of permalinks as the `bookitall_roomtypes` field.

With that in mind, and also to make it clearer `bookitall_roomstype` CPT name is not the same as `bookitall_roomtypes` custom field, I would suggest something like this:

```
// pull an ACF field that has the post ID saved
$room_type_ids = get_field('bookitall_room_type_ids');
// create an empty array to hold room type details
$room_types = array();
foreach($room_type_ids as $room) {
    // save the permalink
    $room_types[][0] = get_the_permalink($room);
    // save the name
    $room_types[][1] = get_the_title($room);
}
// now you can loop through the room types to display as you wish
// this just links the name to the permalink, but you can add whatever
// markup you need
foreach($room_types as $room_details) {
    echo '<a href="' . $room_details[0] . '">' . $room_details[1] . '</a>';
}
```

This way you're only pulling the minimum information required, and not every single roomtype, followed by each roomtype's details, only then to check whether you need those particular details for the current post or not. :)

Comment: Actually I need the other fields as well of the CPT (sorry for not making that clear). I only need one specific roomtype (the select roomtype for the booking) and not a list of the roomtypes. Your code will not work when appending $room_types[][0] and then appending $room_types[][1] in the same iteration. .(there will be two items where the first item has key 0 and the second item in the array has the key 1). I do not understand what you mean it's not safe. It's just a comparision? Even I change the permalink it will work.

Comment: Sorry. I accidently put my updated code (for review) into your posting here. You can remove it if you want :-)